# c++ error c4430 after trying to double multiset object

Tags: c++, namespaces

In a couple of classes (in vlr namespace) in header files I have a public member of this form:

```
std::multiset<classA,classB::ClassC> data_;
```

in my program it is emptied somewhere and so I want to create a buffer to store its content before it is lost.
so under every line of declaration the old member in classes in headers I add such a line:

```
std::multiset<classA,classB::ClassC> data_buff_;
```

and then for buffering I write in some .cpp file:

```
data_buff_.insert(data_);
```

and obtain here **errorC4430: missing type specifier, int assumed.**
Can you help me, how should I properly buffer this data, because I was trying with giving namespace in the line I get error, and nothing helped.

Many thanks!
 - - - - - - - - - update - - - - - - - -

ClassA.h:

```
namespace vlr {
    class A{
     // some unimportant things
    }
}
```

ClassB.h:

```
namespace vlr {
    class B{
     // some unimportant things
     public:
     class C{
        // some unimportant things
     }
    }
}
```

ClassD.h:

```
#include <set>
#include "ClassA.h"
#include "ClassB.h"

namespace vlr {
 class D {
 public:
 std::multiset<classA,classB::ClassC> data_;
 std::multiset<classA,classB::ClassC> data_buff_;
 // some other methods and members
 }
}
```

ClassE.h:

```
#include <set>
#include "ClassA.h"
#include "ClassB.h"

namespace vlr {
 class E {
 public:
 std::multiset<classA,classB::ClassC> data_;
 std::multiset<classA,classB::ClassC> data_buff_;
 // some other methods and members
 }
}
```

final.cpp:

```
#include <set>
#include "ClassA.h"
#include "ClassB.h"
#include "ClassD.h"
#include "ClassE.h"
namespace vlr{
 // something
 data_buff_.insert(data_);
 data_.clear();
}
```

Comment: Why not just `data_buff_ = data_`?

Comment: Did you `#include <set>` (and "classA.h", "classB.h", "classC.h")?

Comment: @Bret Kuhns yes, added this include. btw it is in the same headers as **data_**, and with **data_** alone was working just fine (but i want to copy this content)

Comment: @Vaughn Cato I tried, but then I get the same error and also **C2065: data_ undeclared specifier**

Comment: According to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/multiset/ you should just be able to do an assignment to do a copy.  The insert is done for an element and not for the entire multiset.

Comment: @Richard Chambers sure, I read this also, and I'm confused why I get this error. I have like:
1-> `file1.h
#include <set>
std::multiset<classA,classB::ClassC> data_;
std::multiset<classA,classB::ClassC> data_buff_;`
2-> `file2.h
#include <set>
std::multiset<classA,classB::ClassC> data_;
std::multiset<classA,classB::ClassC> data_buff_;`
3-> `file_exe.cpp
#include "file1.h"
#include "file2.h"
#include <set>
#include "classA.h"
#include "classB.h"
...
data_buff_.insert(data_);` I don't include classC because it is inside classB

Comment: It would help to see what classA and classB look like.  I am curious what the classB::ClassC looks like as well.  Can you update your question.

Comment: @Richard Chambers  done, hope now it's more clear, although it's a  long code

Comment: So `classB::ClassC` has a comparison operator for `classA` types?

Comment: the code looks like above, but before I can answer you this question, I need some reference to understand parameters in multiset. I'm searching and only find simple explanations with one parameter on the net, can you explain or point me to some source? Need to understand what is the 2nd operator or what happens if there is only one (2nd just deleted)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be inserting a multiset into a multiset of the same type. The [`std::multiset::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset/insert) method expects a object of value_type for that particular multiset. If you just want to copy the `data_` multimap into `data_buff_` then you can assign it:

```
data_buff_ = data_;
```

If you want to append the elements of `data_` to `data_buf_`, you can use the two iterator overload of `insert()`:

```
data_.insert(data_.begin(), data_.end());
```

A multiset of this type:

```
std::multiset<classA,classB::ClassC>
```

can hold objects of type `classA`. You can only really insert `classA` object into it. The second argument, `classB::classC`, should be a type used to compare instances of type `classA`. It is used internally to organize the binary tree structure of the set. Such a comparison type must implement [strict weak ordering](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html). In your case, it could be something of the form

```
classB {
 public:
   classC {
    public:
     bool operator() (const classA& lhs&, const classA rhs&) const {
       return lhs.x() < rhs.x();
     }
   };
};
```

Comment: yes, it's multiset into multiset. I'm not sure if I understand you well, I have to create object and then put this object as insert argument? can you maybe show on simple pseudocode an example please, for clarity?

Comment: @eco_student you cannot insert a multiset of type `X` into another  multiset of type `X`. Sets hold elements of a certain type. In your case, the elements are of type `classA`. You can only insets elements of that type.

Comment: @eco_student I added an example showing how to append the elements of one multiset to another one.

Comment: @juanchopanzai appreciate. can you maybe short explain what is then the second element in multiset? from here www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/multiset/begin/ I cannot understand because there is only multiset<int> example, and I think i got it wrong. also what did you do by this line: `data_.insert(data_.begin(), data_.end());`?

Comment: @eco_student the second template parameter is the type of a comparison functor. I added something about this in my answer. See also [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset).